# Use BERT for feature extraction of a unique word

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, language-model

I am using BERT for feature extraction of a word given the text where it appears, but it seems current implementation in bert's official github (https://github.com/google-research/bert) can only compute the features of all the words in text, which makes it consume too much resources. Is it possible to adapt it for this purporse? Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BERT is not a context-free transformer, which means that you don't want to use it for a single word as you would use word2vec. It's kind of the point really -- you want to contextualise your input. I mean you can have a one-word sentence input but then why not just use word2vec.

Here's what the README says:

> Pre-trained representations can also either be context-free or
>   contextual, and contextual representations can further be
>   unidirectional or bidirectional. Context-free models such as word2vec
>   or GloVe generate a single "word embedding" representation for each
>   word in the vocabulary, so bank would have the same representation in
>   bank deposit and river bank. Contextual models instead generate a
>   representation of each word that is based on the other words in the
>   sentence.

Hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in my question. I want to get the features of one word given the word and its contexto. For example, in the sentence " I went to the bank to withdraw money" I want to input the whole sentence to BERT but I only want to get the features of "bank", not the other words.